# Using spacyr for named entity recognition - inconsistent results

Tags: r, spacy

I plan to use the `spacyr` R library to perform named entity recognition across several news articles (`spacyr` is an R wrapper for the Python `spaCy` package). My goal is to identify partners for network analysis automatically.  However, `spacyr` is not recognising common entities as expected. Here is sample code to illustrate my issue:

```
library(quanteda)
library(spacyr)

text <- data.frame(doc_id = c(1:5),
                   sentence = c("Brightmark LLC, the global waste solutions provider, and Florida Keys National Marine Sanctuary (FKNMS), today announced a new plastic recycling partnership that will reduce landfill waste and amplify concerns about ocean plastics.",
                                "Brightmark is launching a nationwide site search for U.S. locations suitable for its next set of advanced recycling facilities, which will convert hundreds of thousands of tons of post-consumer plastics into new products, including fuels, wax, and other products.",
                                "Brightmark will be constructing the facility in partnership with the NSW government, as part of its commitment to drive economic growth and prosperity in regional NSW.",
                                "Macon-Bibb County, the Macon-Bibb County Industrial Authority, and Brightmark have mutually agreed to end discussions around building a plastic recycling plant in Macon",
                                "Global petrochemical company SK Global Chemical and waste solutions provider Brightmark have signed a memorandum of understanding to create a partnership that aims to take the lead in the circular economy of plastic by construction of a commercial scale plastics renewal plant in South Korea"))

corpus <- corpus(text, text_field = "sentence")

spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_sm")

parsed <- spacy_parse(corpus)

entity <- entity_extract(parsed)
```

I expect the company "Brightmark" to be recognised in all 5 sentences.  However this is what I get:

```
entity

  doc_id sentence_id                                 entity entity_type
1      1           1 Florida_Keys_National_Marine_Sanctuary         ORG
2      1           1                                  FKNMS         ORG
3      2           1                                   U.S.         GPE
4      3           1                                    NSW         ORG
5      4           1                    Macon_-_Bibb_County         ORG
6      4           1                             Brightmark         ORG
7      4           1                                  Macon         GPE
8      5           1                     SK_Global_Chemical         ORG
9      5           1                            South_Korea         GPE
```

"Brightmark" only appears as an ORG entity type in the 4th sentence (doc_id refers to sentence number). It should show up in all the sentences. The "NSW Government" does not appear at all.

I am still figuring out `spaCy` and `spacyr`. Perhaps someone can advise me why this is happening and what steps I should take to remedy this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the model and achieved better results:

```
spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_trf")

parsed <- spacy_parse(corpus)

entity <- entity_extract(parsed)

entity

   doc_id sentence_id                                       entity entity_type
1       1           1                               Brightmark_LLC         ORG
2       1           1                                 Florida_Keys         GPE
3       1           1                                        FKNMS         ORG
4       2           1                                   Brightmark         ORG
5       2           1                                         U.S.         GPE
6       3           1                                   Brightmark         ORG
7       3           1                                          NSW         GPE
8       3           1                                          NSW         GPE
9       4           1                          Macon_-_Bibb_County         GPE
10      4           1 the_Macon_-_Bibb_County_Industrial_Authority         ORG
11      4           1                                   Brightmark         ORG
12      4           1                                        Macon         GPE
13      5           1                           SK_Global_Chemical         ORG
14      5           1                                   Brightmark         ORG
15      5           1                                  South_Korea         GPE
```

The only downside is that `NSW Government` and `Florida Keys National Marine Sanctuary` are not resolved.  I also get this warning: `UserWarning: User provided device_type of 'cuda', but CUDA is not available.`

Comment: I guess one has to "tune" the `SpaCy` model some how.